# How to refresh Sonar issues from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube

in the previous versions of the plugin, there used to be a refresh button in the "Sonar Issues" view but since my last upgrade the refresh button seems to have disappeared and I cannot find any replacement.

In the project properties, I can see that my last analysis dates back to September whereas on the server the full analysis is done everyday...

Any idea about what is going on and how I can refresh the Sonar issues view?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to run a new analysis in Eclipse to refresh the issues: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Working+with+SonarQube+in+Eclipse#WorkingwithSonarQubeinEclipse-RunninganAnalysis

Comment: Is there any other way? I have over 20 projects in my workspace and it can take a very long time to analyse all of them. This is why we have automated everything with maven and hudson so developers don't have to run them individually...

Comment: The objective of Eclipse is that developers run preview analysis before committing their code. SonarQube 4.0 / SonarQube Eclipse 3.3 provide an incremental mode by default, so analyses should be quite fast.

Comment: What about issues from other developers? They don't show in the view unless I run analyze. That is not really helpful.
At the Moment I see like 5 Critical issues, but when I inspect them they are not there anymore. This in a workspace with 30 projects.